# Creating Android Weekview on HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a mobile website with a feature where a store owner can set business hours (check the attachments for illustrations) [store hours screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmZmc.png)[image: store hours screen after data input]

Basically, I want to have a widget like the one in the pictures to let user choose hours. I am new to web designing and I have tried search Jquery library for some widget looking like this and couldn't find any.

I am wondering if any one here can give me any suggestions or help in how to best go about developing this feature.

If you have done android, this widget is called weekview in Android.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS  I am new to this site, so please feel free to edit tags if I have added something wrong.

Comment: Take a look at chartjs http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: You could also try jQuery UI slider and set the range to minutes in the day. [link](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical)

Comment: @JulianEspinosa, Thanks for your suggestion. I checkout chart.js, they don't have range bar chart. I don't think I can use it for this example.